# view not showing

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

Greetings guys,

I am a newbie in iphone programming. Basically my problem is the following:

I have a view which have inside an info button and a `UIScrollView` and inside this scrollview I have programatically added buttons with images.

When I press the info button the next view shows up, however when I press a button from scrollview nothing happens knowing that it is catching the click and it is accessing the function that is responsible for showing the next view.

```
- (void)showFlipid)sender{
  FlipsideViewController *controller = initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];
  controller.delegate = self;
  NSlog(@"1"); // IT IS SHOWING WHEN I PRESS A BUTTON FROM UISCRoll
  controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code is missing critical line.
Try to add :

```
[self presentModalViewController:navigation animated:YES];
```

at the end of your code.

BTW
you should release the controller at the end.

Comment: can you describe what are you doing before calling this function?

Comment: Sorry i pasted the wrong function <code> - (void)showFlip:(id)sender{ FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil]; controller.delegate = self; NSlog(@"1"); // IT IS SHOWING WHEN I PRESS A BUTTON FROM UISCRoll controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal; [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES]; [controller release]; } <code> –

Comment: ok i am doing the following

i have utility application
i have inside the mainviewapplication a scrollview and inside it i have added UIbuttons on UIImageView

The buttons are clickable and everything and they trigger the function i want but the view ain't changing

as you know in this app there is an I button by default in the main view

this button is using the same function however when i click the view changes